# Adding a horizontal rule between fields of a Struts 2 form?

Tags: html, css, jsp, struts2

I have a form defined as:

```xml
<s:form id="myForm" action="myFormAction">
    <s:hidden name="ID" />
    <sj:submit/>
    <s:select name="color.id" label="Color" labelposition="top" listKey="id" listValue="name" list="%{#application.colorSelect}"/>
    <s:textarea name="color.notes" cols="120" rows="5" label="Color Notes" labelposition="top"/>
    <s:select name="brightness.id" label="Brightness" labelposition="top" listKey="id" listValue="name" list="%{#application.brightnessSelect}"/>
    <s:textarea name="brightness.notes" cols="120" rows="5" label="Brightness Notes" labelposition="top"/>
</s:form>
```

It renders as expected, but I want to have horizontal rules `<hr/>` above, below, and between the `"color"` and `"brightness"` sections.  Adding them to the Struts form renders them all above the form.

How can I interleave them in the form?

Answer (score 0):

The form tag renders HTML in table layout. Struts tags by default render HTML internally using freemarker templates.

There's a way to change a template using `template` attribute in the struts tags.

Also you can change a `theme` attribute. The default theme used is `xhtml`. There's a theme with the name `simple` which has a minimal HTML layout.

You can find an eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36317433/573032).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27229359/573032) answer would tell you how to set a theme globally using Struts configuration constant.